# Why is Eevee animation render different from a single image render?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, keyframes, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render an animation of a scene that I have previously rendered an image of successfully but the animation render is ignoring keyframes and some of the shader nodes but not all. When I play the animation in the 3D viewport it works perfectly, just not in the animation render. How can I fix this?